# Using WebHDFS to play video over HTTP

Tags: hadoop, ffmpeg, libx264, webhdfs

I used ffmpeg + libx264 to convert file format as H264, then uploaded the file to Hadoop. I used WebHDFS to access the file by HTTP, but can not online play. If I download this file over HTTP, it can play by HTML5 video. My English is poor, hope you know what I mean.

Comment: I try to IE10 and Safari, they can play, but Chrome cannot.

Comment: how are you converting video to H264 format?

Comment: I used ffmpeg command: ffmpeg -y -i /file-path -s 1024*768 -vcodec libx264 ..., I think maybe Webhdfs HTTP protocol didn't match Chrome, because Chrome can play in local(source scr="file:///..."), but use HTTP cannot, but HTTP can play in IE10 and Safari.

Comment: test code:  <html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"></head>
<body><video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="http://192.168.0.12:50075/webhdfs/v1/ambitfs/vod/V150123194507541236/test_0126.mp4?op=OPEN&namenoderpcaddress=hdpcls&offset=0" type="video/mp4"></video>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason, the format of converted file was crash, need to use qt-faststart tool fix it, then can play, thanks.